# error while renaming WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, rename

I created a WCF service (the regular templete one) and tried to access the service. after that everything was fine. after i renamed (using refactoring  the name of IService and Service) OSDataService and IOSDataService i got the following error while accessing the srv file :
[image]

how can i rename it without getting this error? 
i tried also changing it in the web.config file and still the same problem.
Anybody had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well solved it:
you need first to rename the Iservice on the solution explorer, then refactor the service and refactor again all the data (VS2010 will tell you what to do) only then rename the service name (on the solution explorer)

Comment: +1 wow thanks man. I renamed the .cs in VS and THEN the .svc and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

You have to view the markup of the service file and change this in the directive to be the new name because it doesn't change automatically

Right click on the service name, then chose "view markup" and then change the "Class" attribute to be the new name.

Comment: all i got in the .svc file is     <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService2.Service1" CodeBehind="OSDataInfo.svc.cs" %>  no class

Comment: change it to be <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService2.`OSDataService`" CodeBehind="OSDataInfo.svc.cs" %>

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .svc-file? Have you updated the markup in that file if you have one?

Do a search in the whole solution after the old service name and you will moste likely find the file that need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You must update the reference in the client. Or update the stubs manually, but I wouldn't recommend that.